# TypeError: $(...).magnificPopup is not a function - unable to load js files when I change culture

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, multilingual

My HTML is using a lot of js files (6 js files) including jquery js .
When i change the culture, some file does not load.

My html looks this way

```js
 <script src="~/Scripts/library/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/Home/lory.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/Home/modalEffects.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/Home/classie.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/library/jqueryval.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/library/localstorage.js"></script>
```

I got the below error.

> TypeError: $(...).magnificPopup is not a function $('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({ registration.js (line 5) ReferenceError: lory is not defined // lory(multiSlides, { localhost:50978 (line 12, col 12

I am working on a web based application build in asp.net mvc4. and jquery as client side. 
Its multi lingual site. English,  french, Spanish and Portuguese.

All languages are working fine except Portuguese. When I select Portuguese some javascript file are not loading. and its working fine in other languages.

same code works for all other languages

thanks in advance.

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: yes, i got error like this

TypeError: $(...).magnificPopup is not a function 

$('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({

registration.js (line 5)

ReferenceError: lory is not defined

//            lory(multiSlides, {
 
localhost:50978 (line 12, col 12

Comment: TypeError: $(...).magnificPopup is not a function

Comment: ReferenceError: lory is not defined

Comment: You've stated that only a certain language is has this problem. is there are seperate template files for each language? if so, please check on the order of the libraries defined there! The order of them are important! first jQuery then the other libraries!

Comment: Hi Dimal,
Thanks for uor reply.

Yes this issue happens with a particular language. I have four different language in my project, (en, es, fr, and pt). Except pt all were working fine

Comment: No i am not using any separate file for this particular language. I am using the same file(js,css) for all the languages.

Comment: I couldn't assist you with only the provided html.. if you could post how the html is generated when each language is requested, will help a little bit! cannot figure out what is going on!

Answer (score 0):

TypeError: $(...).magnificPopup is not a function Means that some addon is blocking your script from working properly or if you are using adblock, it's probably blocking this script and interfering.

Had the same problem, My adblock seemed to cause it.

Comment: if this happens because of adblocker, then why is it working for other languages.

If the issue is with adblocker, it block other languages too.

Comment: I am merely explaining what was my solution :) is your javascript separate for each and every language? maybe there is an addon for the Portuguese site that is causing the trouble.

Comment: JavaScript files are same for each language.there is separate file for Portuguese or other language